# Order details page is disturbed on admin side Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, sales-order, js-css

When i goto my order details page its look disturbed ,i think some css or something missing that disturb the layout.I replace the sales folder and upload new css but still no luck.What else i try to set that ? I tried to disable extensions but no luck again.My page look like this :
[image]

I got this error on enabling the logs.

```
2015-02-09T05:24:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /home/firstchoicedds/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

Comment: Mahmood Rehman,Please enable system.log and excpetion .log check where the issue

Comment: @AmitBera Thanks i have add my error on question area.After logs checking  got this issue

Comment: I have removed that error by going to that extension and set it disable.Its showing now no error but still getting same result.

Comment: Try using Chrome Dev Tools (for Google Chrome) or Firebug (for Mozilla Firefox) to see if there are any JavaScript errors in the console.

Comment: @moose When i enable js combine option from admin side then i see some errors on console but when i disable the option i get no error .so i think no js issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debuggind and testing i found solution for my problem.I am not sure that it is relaiabl to what extent but my orders are showing properly.I goto `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php` and change the `canReorderIgnoreSalable()` to `canReorder()`.I found that issue on logs that was

```
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::canReorderIgnoreSalable(Array
(
)
```

May be it helps someone.